# Linkedin Webscrape w Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, web-scraping

I am new to web development and scraping in general and I am trying to challenge myself by scrape websites like LinkedIn.
Since they have embers and dynamically changing ids it is a bit more struggle to scrape properly.

I am trying to scrape the "experience section" of a LinkedIn profile by looking using the following code:

```
experience = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//section[@id = "experience-section"]/ul/li[@class="position"]')
```

the driver got the entire Linkedin profile webpage. I would like to have all the position under the "experience-section". The error message is:

*Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//section[@id = "experience-section"]/ul/li/div[@class="position"]"}*

I am able to scrape other stuff on Linkedin, but the experience section is a big struggle for me. Is the xpath wrong? if yes, what could I change?

Thank you

```html
<section id="experience-section" class="pv-profile-section experience-section ember-view"><header class="pv-profile-section__card-header">
  <h2 class="pv-profile-section__card-heading t-20 t-black t-normal">
    Experience
  </h2>

<!----></header>

<ul id="ember1620" class="pv-profile-section__section-info section-info pv-profile-section__section-info--has-no-more ember-view"><li id="ember1622" class="pv-profile-section__sortable-item pv-profile-section__section-info-item relative pv-profile-section__list-item sortable-item ember-view"><div id="ember1623" class="pv-entity__position-group-pager ember-view">            <li id="392598211" class="pv-profile-section__sortable-card-item pv-profile-section pv-position-entity ember-view"><!----><a data-control-name="background_details_company" href="/company/8736/" id="ember1626" class="ember-view">      <div class="pv-entity__logo company-logo">
  <img class="lazy-image pv-entity__logo-img pv-entity__logo-img EntityPhoto-square-5 loaded" alt="Bill &amp; Melinda Gates Foundation" src="https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C560BAQHvFIyUvuKtQA/company-logo_400_400/0?e=1556755200&amp;v=beta&amp;t=Qhh8_KnrE-OiuXAutFyeI69tgUF3c1ptC9N12siDO4o">
</div>
<div class="pv-entity__summary-info pv-entity__summary-info--background-section ">
  <h3 class="t-16 t-black t-bold">Co-chair</h3>

  <h4 class="t-16 t-black t-normal">
    <span class="visually-hidden">Company Name</span>
    <span class="pv-entity__secondary-title">Bill &amp; Melinda Gates Foundation</span>
  </h4>

    <div class="display-flex">
    <h4 class="pv-entity__date-range t-14 t-black--light t-normal">
      <span class="visually-hidden">Dates Employed</span>
      <span>2000 – Present</span>
    </h4>
      <h4 class="t-14 t-black--light t-normal">
        <span class="visually-hidden">Employment Duration</span>
        <span class="pv-entity__bullet-item-v2">19 yrs</span>
      </h4>
  </div>

<!---->
</div>

</a>
<!---->
</li>


</div>
</li><li id="ember1630" class="pv-profile-section__sortable-item pv-profile-section__section-info-item relative pv-profile-section__list-item sortable-item ember-view"><div id="ember1631" class="pv-entity__position-group-pager ember-view">            <li id="392599749" class="pv-profile-section__sortable-card-item pv-profile-section pv-position-entity ember-view"><!----><a data-control-name="background_details_company" href="/company/1035/" id="ember1634" class="ember-view">      <div class="pv-entity__logo company-logo">
  <img class="lazy-image pv-entity__logo-img pv-entity__logo-img EntityPhoto-square-5 loaded" alt="Microsoft" src="https://media.licdn.com/dms/image/C4D0BAQEko6uLz7XylA/company-logo_400_400/0?e=1556755200&amp;v=beta&amp;t=XQhwV5ruWfGBfjgQylV9gkeXD8VnQRBHGd1bOfTs2tw">
</div>
<div class="pv-entity__summary-info pv-entity__summary-info--background-section ">
  <h3 class="t-16 t-black t-bold">Co-founder</h3>

  <h4 class="t-16 t-black t-normal">
    <span class="visually-hidden">Company Name</span>
    <span class="pv-entity__secondary-title">Microsoft</span>
  </h4>

    <div class="display-flex">
    <h4 class="pv-entity__date-range t-14 t-black--light t-normal">
      <span class="visually-hidden">Dates Employed</span>
      <span>1975 – Present</span>
    </h4>
      <h4 class="t-14 t-black--light t-normal">
        <span class="visually-hidden">Employment Duration</span>
        <span class="pv-entity__bullet-item-v2">44 yrs</span>
      </h4>
  </div>

<!---->
</div>

</a>
<!---->
</li>


</div>
</li>
</ul>
<!----></section>
```

---- Update: 
I used the solution provided by Sers

```
driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/in/williamhgates/')
experience = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//section[@id = "experience-section"]/ul//li')
for item in experience:
    print(item.text)
    print("")
```

and I somehow get the results twice:

```html
Co-chair
Company Name
Bill & Melinda Gates Foundation
Dates Employed
2000 – Present
Employment Duration
19 yrs

Co-chair
Company Name
Bill & Melinda Gates Foundation
Dates Employed
2000 – Present
Employment Duration
19 yrs

Co-founder
Company Name
Microsoft
Dates Employed
1975 – Present
Employment Duration
44 yrs

Co-founder
Company Name
Microsoft
Dates Employed
1975 – Present
Employment Duration
44 yrs
```

Comment: Can your please post the html where you are getting problem.

Comment: added the html code

Comment: I don't see any elements with `@class` value equal to "position". Which node are you targeting? Did you mean to test whether it **contains** "position" in the `@class`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem in you xpath is `li` not directly under `ul`, try xpath below:

```
//section[@id = "experience-section"]/ul//li
```

Update

```
driver.get('https://www.linkedin.com/in/williamhgates/')
experience = driver.find_elements_css_selector('#experience-section .pv-profile-section')
for item in experience:
    print(item.text)
    print("")
```

Comment: I knew it was something basic. It worked! Thank you very much. However, if I use it the following way: `experience = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//section[@id = "experience-section"]/ul//li')` I get duplicates when I print the results: `for item in experience:
    print(item.text)`

Comment: I got the Co-Chair role twice in my results. What could be the problem?

Comment: @meecrob share you code. Also feel free to accept the answer

Comment: I did update the original post. I ll mark your answer as solved

Comment: @meecrob check my update, I changed xpath to css selector.

Comment: Yes it works (with * find_elements_by_css_selector). Could you elaborate on why this works and what are the problems with the previous? Thank you! Much appreciated!

Comment: Reason is `li` element inside another `li` and because I didn't specify exactly which `li` element get in my xpath, selector gave you twice "same" result. First for parent `li` then child `li`. In css selector I used unique `.pv-profile-section` class of `li` element. Same can be done with xpath also, but I prefer to you use css selector, because it much shorter and easier. Here is how xpath will look like `//section[@id = "experience-section"]//li[contains(@class,'pv-profile-section')]`.