# Get the experience section of a linkedin profile with selenium and python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to get information from the experience and Education section.

For example of this linkedin profile:https://www.linkedin.com/in/kendra-tyson/

I want to get the information of all the experience section and education section.

For now I've been working on the Experience section. I want to get the container that has all the different jobs in the Experience sections I can iterate through the container and get the individual jobs (ie,
Talent Acquisition & Human Resources Manager, Technical Recruiter)

I'm using find elements by xpath with selenium but it times out/doesn't find the xpath.

```
   experience = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, make_xpath_experience)))
```

The xpaths that I have tried are :

```
make_xpath_experience = "//div[@id='experience']/div[.//h2[text()='Experience']]//ul[contains(@class, 'pvs-list')]"
make_xpath_experience = "//section[@id='experience']//li[contains(@class, 'pvs-list__outer-container')]"
```

and I also tried CSS selector per this stackoverflow question with the updated information as the parameters used in that answer are no longer available: [Linkedin Webscrape w Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54392465/linkedin-webscrape-w-selenium)

```
experience = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#experience . pvs-list__outer-container')))
```

I also tried following this geeksforgeeks tutorial with beautifulsoup (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scrape-linkedin-using-selenium-and-beautiful-soup-in-python/) but the information is outdated and does not work.

How can I target the Experience section of the profile and then be able to extract the individual jobs and information (ie. full time, timeline, location)?

Comment: Can't you do this more easily using the API instead of web scraping?

Comment: I cannot find good enough documentation/examples to make the API work for me so I am using selenium and python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code create a dictionary and populate it with jobs name, company, date, location and description.

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
exp = {key:[] for key in ['job','company','date','location','description']}
jobs = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'section:has(#experience)>div>ul>li')
for job in jobs:
    exp['job']     += [job.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[class="mr1 t-bold"] span').text]
    exp['company'] += [job.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[class="t-14 t-normal"] span').text]
    exp['date']    += [job.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[class="t-14 t-normal t-black--light"] span').text]
    try:
        exp['location'] += [job.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[class="t-14 t-normal t-black--light"]:nth-child(4) span').text]
    except NoSuchElementException:
        exp['location'] += ['*missing value*']
    try:
        exp['description'] += [job.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'ul li ul span[aria-hidden=true]').text]
    except NoSuchElementException:
        exp['description'] += ['*missing value*']

import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame(exp)
```

[image]

and if you want you can export the table in a csv file.

## Update 3

Using javascript we can avoid using try except blocks. If location or description is missing, there will be `None` instead of `*missing value*`, as you can see from image below.

```
exp = {key:[] for key in ['job','company','date','location','description']}
jobs = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'section:has(#experience)>div>ul>li')
for job in jobs:
    exp['job']     += [job.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[class="mr1 t-bold"] span').text]
    exp['company'] += [job.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[class="t-14 t-normal"] span').text]
    exp['date']    += [job.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[class="t-14 t-normal t-black--light"] span').text]
    exp['location']    += [driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].querySelector("span[class=\'t-14 t-normal t-black--light\']:nth-child(4) span")?.innerText', job)]
    exp['description'] += [driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].querySelector("ul li ul span[aria-hidden=true]")?.innerText', job)]
```

[image]

The javascript command

```
driver.execute_script('return arguments[0].querySelector(css_selector)?.innerText', arg0)
```

works in this way

- `arguments[0]` is a placeholder for `arg0`. In our case `arg0` is a webelement.
- `arguments[0].querySelector(css_selector)` searches for element given by `css_selector` inside the element `arg0`. If you replace `arguments[0]` with `document`, then it will search in all the HTML.
- `.innerText` extract the text contained inside the node found by the `querySelector`
- `?.innerText` means that `.innerText` is executed only if `querySelector` finds something.
- `execute_script` returns `None` if `querySelector` doesn't find anything, thanks to this we can avoid the try except block

Comment: This works and it's what I'm looking for but could you explain [job.text.split('\n')[0] for job in jobs] further? Specifically the inline for loop. Also, for example, I understand that the [0] in that code says to give the first position of the job section but If I wanted to modify it so I can get for example the years in that job or the second position from the job section. How can I modify it to also get that information? Does the inline for loop make a difference? Would getting the second line of the job description simply be [job.text.split('\n')[1] for job in jobs] under first line?

Comment: @JesperEzra (1/2) That kind of loop is called "list comprehension", it is the one line equivalent of `for job in jobs: job.text.split('\n')[0]`. About getting the second line, yes in principle with [i] you get the i-th line, but it not always true, see for example the code I added in the answer. However, using `.text.split('\n')` is the worst thing one can do.

Comment: @JesperEzra (2/2) The good practice would be to select each element by a unique attribute, but linkedin doesn't use good class names, moreover elements are nested inside many other elements, so it's a bit annoying to find a good xpath. For example the company is inside a `<span class="t-14 t-normal">`, year and location are inside `<span class="t-14 t-normal t-black--light">` and so on, so from class names you don't understand what's inside them. Anyway I will try to do it

Comment: @JesperEzra Look at code in update 2

Comment: This is what I was looking for thank you!! I have a question. Some profiles don't include a location or description. In order to account for that I include a try and except for those two to account for both cases. Is there a more efficient/better way to account for both cases where it might include location/description or it might not?

Comment: @JesperEzra Yes best thing is to use try except with NoSuchElementException, check out the updated code. I tried the code after manually removing one location and one description from the linkedin page, and as you can see from the screenshot there are two `*missing value*`

Comment: @JesperEzra Actually I found out that try except can be avoided by using javascript command `driver.execute_script(...)`. Look at update 3 in the answer