# scrap College name out of education section linkedin with python and selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am continuing this project after being scrapped for a while.

I asked a similar question below to get the experience section and applied it to the education section of a LinkedIn profile:
[Get the experience section of a linkedin profile with selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75539164/get-the-experience-section-of-a-linkedin-profile-with-selenium-and-python)

This used to work at the time when I asked this question. Now it's complaining that I can't find the college in the education section of a LinkedIn profile.

I thought maybe the HTML got changed. However, I checked, and it remains the same.

The full section of the code is as follows:

```
 for education in edu:
            driver.implicitly_wait(30)
            ed['College'] += [education.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[class=\'mr1 hoverable-link-text\'] span').text]
            ed['Degree'] += [driver.execute_script(
                'return arguments[0].querySelector("span[class=\'t-14 t-normal\']:nth-child(2) span")?.innerText',
                education)]
```

The code that stopped working is the following:

```
#ed['College'] += [education.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[class=\'mr1 hoverable-link-text\'] span').text]
```

I also tried to do the following, which worked for the experience section, when it stopped working.

```
ed['College'] += [driver.execute_script(
                'return arguments[0].querySelector("span[class$=\'t-bold\']:nth-child(1) span")?.innerText',
                education)]
```

Here's that section:

```
<div class="display-flex align-items-center
      mr1 hoverable-link-text t-bold">
    <span aria-hidden="true"><!----><!----></span><span class="visually-hidden"><!----><!----></span>
  </div>
```

It might be something silly, but I do not understand why it no longer finds the CSS.

Please advise.