# Python and Selenium: How to extract experience info from LinkedIn profile?

Tags: python, html, css, selenium-webdriver

I need to extract info from a professional experience section like the following and store the result in a dataframe.
https://www.linkedin.com/in/maxlvsq/details/experience/

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8asV.png)

I have been reading about how to do it, including this stack overflow thread: [Get the experience section of a linkedin profile with selenium and python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75539164/get-the-experience-section-of-a-linkedin-profile-with-selenium-and-python), which proposes this solution:

```
jobs = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'section:has(#experience)>div>ul>li')
for job in jobs:
    exp['job']     += [job.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[class="mr1 t-bold"] span').text]
    exp['company'] += [job.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[class="t-14 t-normal"] span').text]
    exp['date']    += [job.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[class="t-14 t-normal t-black--light"] span').text]
    try:
        exp['location'] += [job.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[class="t-14 t-normal t-black--light"]:nth-child(4) span').text]
    except NoSuchElementException:
        exp['location'] += ['*missing value*']
    try:
        exp['description'] += [job.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'ul li ul span[aria-hidden=true]').text]
    except NoSuchElementException:
        exp['description'] += ['*missing value*']
```

This solution however does not work for me, because the elements do not exist anymore under those names. Here is what I tried. I can get out the description and timeframes (but I face the issue that the lists have different length). For the position, company name, and location I have not been able to find the class or id names.

```
# description
descriptions = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'pvs-list__outer-container')


# timeframes
timeframes = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'pvs-entity__caption-wrapper')
```

Is there anyone who knows how to fix that?
Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

[image]
So what happened was that the selector you use no longer works, try the below

based on the link you gave

```
jobs = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,'pvs-list__paged-list-item')
```

Comment: Nice, that does not return an empty list. However with the code from the other stack overflow thread I run into another error. It seems the element with class "mr1 t-bold" doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: no the code does return 15 element

Comment: Yes it return 15 elements. But how can I access the content. For example job.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[class="mr1 t-bold"] span') doesn't work anymore.

Comment: And your solution contains all of the info in an unseparated format which is difficult to parse. Is there a way to extract the info separately?

Comment: i just updated it with the image;i you just need is to find a unique selector or class name why scrapping

Comment: How can I extract all of the elements by their ID. I noticed they end on ...US-0, ...US-1 and so on. Is their a way to extract all of those?

Comment: find_elements(By.XPATH, "//li[contains(@id, 'US-')]")

Comment: Look, I just updated the question !

Comment: It will have been better to create another thread so that others facing similar issue would have use this thread

Comment: Sorry about that, I have now completely reworked the questions. Do you still think it would be better to start a new question?